# How to import with ECMAScript (vanilla javascript) with modules es6

Tags: javascript, d3.js, umd

I read this [post](https://philipwalton.com/articles/deploying-es2015-code-in-production-today/) and i want use D3.js (v4+) using only import statement like this:

```
import { selection } from '../node modules/d3/build/d3.js';
```

But, because code output is [UMD](https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/index.html#umd-universal-module-definition) (or read [this](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)) and can't import because some globals is no defined, and ES6 can't resolve absolutive names in `node_modules` for example and vanilla don't suport import statement without extension like this:

```
import * as someFeature from './myAwesomeModule';
```

And this is pattern to import modules and each day is growing up [like you see here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module).

How i can use import statement without any plugin today?

Answer (score 1):

You can import d3 like this:

`import * as d3 from 'd3';`

See more here: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/README.md#installing

Comment: Thanks for answer my question but this no work in vanilla because browser can't find module without path only with other plugin like roll-up or webpack like your link show.

Comment: In 2024, it is possible to do this with vanilla JS. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77875559/119901