# Is it possible to get hints from external js lib in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

For example in html file I have
`<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>` and I want to get hints like `d3->csv` etc.

In WebStorm it is possible by adding `https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js` to `External Libraries`. Is there a way to do so in VSCode?

It is in a simple HTML+JS file without npm, node etc. like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        d3.SHOW_HINTS
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like Mike said it can be done by including the TS typings. Even though you don't use TS you can still get the typing information in JS file. Can you show your project structure/setup so I can provide more detailed instruction?

Comment: @hackape Thanks, I don't know how that could help, but I have updated the question with the code. it is a simple HTML file, and as I said in intelij webstrom it works great with to External Libraries

Comment: It does help, since it tells me you want the hint feature inside `<script>` tag in HTML file. Unfortunately vscode official extension doesn't support that. Currently you can only go with moving the script into standalone JS file to enable hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your `d3` use case, all you need to do is:

1. move your `<script>` tag content from HTML file into a standalone JS file.
2. `npm install @types/d3`, like Mike Lischke has already pointed out

The result:

[image]

You cannot get the same kind of IntelliSense hint within the `<script>` tag inside a HTML file, since the official extension doesn't support it. Please refer to my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077427/3617380) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

What you are after is the intellisense information, which is provided by the JS/TS language implementation. Beside the actual TS code (if provided) it uses socalled [typings (or declaration) files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html). There are typings for many different libraries. For D3.js use `npm install @types/d3` or add `"@types/d3": "^5.7.2"` to your dev-dependencies section in package.json and run `npm install` after that.

Comment: I don't use nmp or TS etc. Just a pure HTML file with some JS code

Comment: @SERG Javascript uses the Typescript Language Server to do the intellisense. But as you don't so a `require` or `import` `window.d3` is not a known variable and thus no intellisense possible

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, I am able to get this working by putting my script in a separate JS that I included like this:

```html
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

And the including a line like this at the top of that `script.js` file:

```js
import "https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js";
```

Comment: No NPM or TS required.

Comment: By doing this, are you able to see the intellisense, like you would normally get in TS when you are using the TS+NPM combo?