# intellisense for global JS scripts on website (vanilla) (like jquery etc.) included globally via `<link>` on pages

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, web

I have a very simple vanilla page — a bunch of `.html` and `.js` files. I also use some scripts from CDN like `jQuery` and `highlight.js`. I add them using `<link>` tags on my pages.

Is there any way to add intellisense for those externally linked scripts inside my `*.js` files in VSCode?

Currently I am working with Jekyll, so I don't have any `npm` package setup, nor any webpack etc (I don't even know how webpack works)

Normally in node I use `import _ from <package installed with npm>`. Is there anything similar when writing a website?

Comment: [related topic with d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410535/is-it-possible-to-get-hints-from-external-js-lib-in-vscode).
TL;DR use `@types/<package>`, move scripts to `.js` files, access global objects. It seems that it's not possible yet for `import lib from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr...'` remote imports in modules.